# Creating new columns based on sum of specific columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows, calculated-columns

I am very new to Python and trying to create a column to indicate whether the sum of few columns are greater than 0 or not.

For example, I have a df that is similar to the one below:

| id | quantity | spent | freq | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | **0** | **0** | **0** | 10/02 |
| a2 | 0 | 10 | 0 | 05/12 |
| a2 | **0** | **0** | **0** | 03/12 |

If a row for 'quantity', 'spent', and 'freq' is all 0, I want to create a new column to indicate that the row has all 0 values like the table below:

| id | quantity | spent | freq | date | not_zero |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 10/02 | **0** |
| a2 | 0 | 10 | 0 | 05/12 | **1** |
| a2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 03/12 | **0** |

Answer (score 1):

Try [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html#pandas-dataframe-any) on axis=1 then [`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html#pandas-series-astype):

```
df['not_zero'] = df[['quantity', 'spent', 'freq']].any(axis=1).astype(int)
```

Or with [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy-where):

```
df['not_zero'] = np.where(df[['quantity', 'spent', 'freq']].any(axis=1), 1, 0)
```

`df`:

```
   id  quantity  spent  freq   date  not_zero
0  a1         0      0     0  10/02         0
1  a2         0     10     0  05/12         1
2  a2         0      0     0  03/12         0
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly create a boolean mask:

```
mask=(df[['quantity','spent','freq']]==0).all(1)
```

Finally:

with `loc` accessor:

```
df.loc[mask,'not_zero']=0
df.loc[~mask,'not_zero']=1
```

**OR**

with `np.where()` method:

```
df['not_zero'] = np.where(mask, 0, 1)
```

Comment: You might consider `df['not_zero'] = np.where(mask, 0, 1)` over two `loc` assignments.